# Using a multiple <select> element in widget form

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, select

I am trying to save all of the options in a `<select>` element in a widget. So far I have the following PHP code for the form:

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    // Code for editing/adding title and adding IDs to the <select> object
    // ...

    <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ID_list'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('ID_list'); ?>[]" multiple>
        <?php
            foreach( $instance['ID_list'] as $id )
            {
                echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $id . '</option>' . "\n";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
}
```

I also created a jQuery handler for the save button at the end of the form, which has the following code:

```
$('input#<?php echo $this->get_field_id('savewidget'); ?>').click( function( event ) {
     $('select#<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ID_list'); ?> option').prop('selected', true);
});
```

I then use the following code for the `update` function of the widget:

```
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
     // Update the title, etc...
     $instance['ID_list'] = isset( $new_instance['ID_list'] ) ? $new_instance['ID_list'] : array();

     return $instance;
}
```

I was hoping that the `$instance['ID_list']` would behave like the `_POST('ID_list')` would in a normal PHP form, and would be a sub-array containing all of the selected elements (in this case all the added IDs), however, this does not appear to happen; what is the idiomatic WordPress way of doing what I want to achieve?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would remove the jQuery save function that was added... and then...

Try this for the form function:

```
public function form( $instance ) {
    // Code for editing/adding title and adding IDs to the <select> object
    // ...

    <?php
            printf (
                '<select multiple="multiple" name="%s[]" id="%s" class="widefat" size="15" style="margin-bottom:10px">',
                $this->get_field_name('ID_list'),
                $this->get_field_id('ID_list')
            );

            // Each individual option
            foreach( $instance['ID_list'] as $id )
            {
                printf(
                    '<option value="%s" %s style="margin-bottom:3px;">%s</option>',
                    $id,
                    in_array( $id, $instance['ID_list']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '',
                    $id
                );
            }

            echo '</select>';
}
```

Alright, try this **update** function:

```
   <?php
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['ID_list'] = esc_sql( $new_instance['ID_list'] );
        $instance['title'] = esc_sql( $new_instance['title']);
        return $instance;
    }
```